# How can I read a text file and specify what type of object it is in Java?

Tags: java, object, text-files, java.util.scanner

So I have a text file that has lots of dogs and cats in it. It looks something like this:

```
Cat Bones 60 150 Orange 3006
Dog Bruce 170 200 210 White 1530
Dog Bones 130 145 200 Black 0864
Cat Mog 70 140 Black 6037
...
```

As you can see, all dogs will have an additional int assigned to them where cats do not. This is the same for all dogs and cats in the list. I want to make objects for each dog and cat and store them in the same array. I want to do this using a scanner and by using the in.next() function and variations of it such as in.nextInt(). The main problem that I have is that I cannot tell which line is a dog and which is a cat so it's causing problems with my in.next(). Dogs have 1 more integer than cats so I have to find a way to identify the dogs from the cats and then set the variables to be passed into the constructor for dog/cat.

The dog constructor looks like this

```
Public Dog(String name, int x, int y, int z, String colour, int ID) {...}
```

The cat constructor looks like this

```
Public Cat(String name, int x, int y, String colour, int ID) {...}
```

I tried to do

```
String objectType = in.next();
String name = in.next();
int x = in.nextInt();
int y = in.nextInt();
if(objectType == "Dog") {
    int z = in.nextInt();
}
String colour = in.next();
int ID = in.next();

if(objectType == "Dog") {
    Dog newDog = new Dog(name, x, y, z, colour, ID);
```

This does not work. The z is in red and 'cannot resolve symbol z'. Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: You're comparing strings wrong. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java

Comment: You can only use variables in the scope in which you declare them, so nothing can see `z` outside of the if-statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should learn about "scopes". If you create z inside the if-condition it is not reachable outside that block. So create it outside the if-condition, then it will work.

```
String objectType = in.next();
String name = in.next();
int x = in.nextInt();
int y = in.nextInt();
int z;
if("Dog".equals(objectType)) {
    z = in.nextInt();
}
String colour = in.next();
int ID = in.next();

if("Dog".equals(objectType)) {
    Dog newDog = new Dog(name, x, y, z, colour, ID);
}
```

Also the == operator works only with simple types (int, long, float, boolean) but not with Objects (Integer, Long, Float, String, ...). For objects you must use the equals() method.

The operator == used on objects would compare the identity (which is the address in RAM) of the objects, not their values.

Comment: Thank you, this has fixed most of my problems but I now I have a red line under z in the newDog part which says that the Variable 'z' might not have been initialized. Any ideas on how to fix this? EDIT: I have set z to equal 0 when it is initialised and it seems to work now. Thank you!

Comment: initialize z with 0: ```int z=0;```. However that warning is surely false.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me to be an exercise in object-oriented programming, i.e. class hierarchies, since class `Cat` and class `Dog` have common members. In fact they have the same members and `Dog` has an extra member, namely `z`.

Also, your input file is like a CSV file that uses a single space as the field delimiter rather than a comma.

Hence I would create a parent class `HousePet`, since cats and dogs are both usually house pets, which contains the members common to both `Cat` and `Dog` and have both those classes extend class `HousePet`.

Then you simply read the file line by line. For each line you split it by the single space delimiter. If the line has six parts it is a `Cat`, otherwise it is a `Dog`. You call the appropriate constructor depending on the number of parts in the line read.

Since you need to add both `Cat`s and `Dog`s to the same list, create a `List` of `HousePet`.

Here is the code.

```java
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CatsDogs {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("catsdogs.txt"))) {
            List<HousePet> pets = new ArrayList<>();
            while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = scanner.nextLine();
                String[] parts = line.split("\\s");
                HousePet pet;
                if (parts.length == 6) {
                    pet = new Cat(parts[1],
                                  Integer.parseInt(parts[2]),
                                  Integer.parseInt(parts[3]),
                                  parts[4],
                                  Integer.parseInt(parts[5]));
                }
                else {
                    pet = new Dog(parts[1],
                                  Integer.parseInt(parts[2]),
                                  Integer.parseInt(parts[3]),
                                  Integer.parseInt(parts[4]),
                                  parts[5],
                                  Integer.parseInt(parts[6]));
                }
                pets.add(pet);
            }
        }
        catch (IOException xIo) {
            xIo.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

abstract class HousePet {
    protected String name;
    protected int x;
    protected int y;
    protected String colour;
    protected int id;

    protected HousePet(String name, int x, int y, String colour, int id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.colour = colour;
        this.id = id;
    }
}

class Cat extends HousePet {
    public Cat(String name, int x, int y, String colour, int id) {
        super(name, x, y, colour, id);
    }
}

class Dog extends HousePet {
    private int z;

    public Dog(String name, int x, int y, int z, String colour, int id) {
        super(name, x, y, colour, id);
        this.z = z;
    }
}
```